# Recursively terminate spawned greenlets

Tags: python, kill, gevent, spawn

```
import gevent

def f1():
    gevent.spawn(f3)
    while True:
        print "f1"
        gevent.sleep(1)

def f2():
    gevent.spawn(f1)
    while True:
        print "f2"
        gevent.sleep(1)

def f3():
    gevent.spawn(f4)
    while True:
        print "f3"
        gevent.sleep(1)

def f4():
    while True:
        print "f4"
        gevent.sleep(1)


g2 = gevent.spawn(f2)
g2.join(timeout=1.0)

def kill(g):
    ##
    ##   kill children here
    ##
    g.kill()



for i in range(100):
    print "--"*4, i
    if i == 10: 
        kill(g2)

    gevent.sleep(1)
```

After the tenth iteration, `kill` is called which kills the greenlet that is running `f2`. Please tell me a way I can kill the greenlets spawned by it recursively so that all 4 are killed.

Comment: Stop violence.  And never, ever, think about killing children.

Comment: To anyone who found this question via google: please turn yourself in

Answer (score 0):

gevent maintains and event queue which starts to run once join() is called. There is no tree structure that is stored, at least not that I know. If you want to kill all spawned children, maintain a list of spawns yourself, and iterate through them to kill.